# How do I provide a ViewRootImpl name to Layout Inspector?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-windowmanager, layout-inspector

I'm inflating four Views and adding them to the WindowManager using the [addView method in the ViewManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)). I'm using Android Studio's Layout Inspector to debug the layout of the views, however when I pull up the list of views in that process I get a list of ViewRootImpls. To make it easier to find the right view, I would like to provide a name that Layout Inspector can find and show instead of the class and the address.

For most of these views, the root layout that I inflate is a container, e.g. ConstraintLayout. Still, that class name isn't resolved, but rather it just shows ViewRootImpl.

I've tried setting a tag on the view, but that did not do anything. I used a hex editor to look at the captured li file and at the top of it sits a "title" tag. I therefore tried to set the title in the WindowManager.LayoutParams used when adding the view, but that didn't do anything.

How do I provide this information to Layout Inspector?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, setting the title in WindowManager.LayoutParams worked after all.